# Ignore the date range parameter in the where clause when parameter is not entered

Tags: oracle

Ignore the date range parameter in the where clause when parameter is not entered. For my date range im using Between.

These parameter are being entered from jasper report

```
SELECT * 
  from customer 
 where client_id = $P{CLIENT_ID} 
   AND (Account_id = CASE WHEN $P{Account_ID}>0 
                          THEN $P{Account_ID} 
                          ELSE Account_ID END 
        OR Account_ID IS NULL ) 
   AND datetrx BETWEEN $P{DATE_START} AND $P{DATE_END}
```

if date is not entered the report should bring records of any dates, since date range is not entered

Comment: Is the SQL text static or you may generate dynamic SQL based on input parameters?

Comment: You could use Oracle's built-in function `nvl`, assuming that an unentered parameter value is the same as a `null`. Are you familiar with that function? If `DATE_START` is null, use another Oracle built-in function `to_date` to create a date so far in the past that all the values of column `datetrx` will be more recent than it.

Comment: thank you for the response @MarmiteBomber yes the sql is dynamic those parameters are entered from a jasper report

Comment: thank you for the response @Abra No im not familiar with nvl, just recently started using oracle. in my case the datetrx is never a null value, but i may not enter a parameter and still want to bring everything with anydate. For now when i with the above i get a blank report if i dont enter the date parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities to approach the optional input paramaters.

The *simpler* way is to use static SQL and providing *default* value for the missing parameters, so that you get all matches.

Here you simple sets the boundaries to the minimum and maximum possible DATE.

```
select * 
from customer
where customer_id = $P{CLIENT_ID}
and datetrx between nvl($P{DATE_START},date'1900-01-01') 
                and nvl($P{DATE_END},date'2200-01-01')
```

The more *advanced* way was popularized by [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1669972300346534908) and is based on using dynamic SQL.

If the *paramaters are provided*, you generate **normal SQL with the `BETWEEN` predicate**:

```
select * 
from customer
where customer_id = $P{CLIENT_ID}
and datetrx between $P{DATE_START} and $P{DATE_END}
```

In case the *parameter are missing* (i.e. `NULL` is passed) you generate a **different SQL** as shown below.

```
select * 
from customer
where customer_id = $P{CLIENT_ID}
and (1=1 or datetrx between $P{DATE_START} and $P{DATE_END})
```

Note, that

1) the number of the bind variables is the same in both variants of the query, which is important as you can use identical `setXXXX` statements

2) due to the *shortcut* `1 = 1 or` is the `between` predicate ignored, i.e. all dates are considered.

**Which option should be used?**

Well for simple queries there will be small difefrence, but for complex queries with several options of missing parameters and large data, *the dynamic SQL approach is preferred*.

The reason is, that using static SQL you use the same statement for more different queries - here one for access *with* data range and one for access *without* data range.

The dynamic option produces different SQL for each access.

You may see it on the [execution plans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122):

**Access with date range**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |     1 |    22 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER           |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| CUST_IDX1 |     1 |    22 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_DATE(:1)<=TO_DATE(:2))
   2 - access("CUSTOMER_ID"=1 AND "DATETRX">=:1 AND "DATETRX"<=:2)
```

**Access without data range**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |           |     1 |    22 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| CUST_IDX1 |     1 |    22 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("CUSTOMER_ID"=1)
```

Both statements produce different execution plan, that is optimised for the input parameter. In the static option use must **share the same execution plan** for all input which may cause problems.