# Escaping characters in select statement withing a cursor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, if-statement, oracle11g, ref-cursor

I have a Function defined in a package that uses a REF CURSOR and IF ELSE logic to assign a select statement to the cursor. The Function executes with an ORA-01722: invalid number error.  I believe this is due to a mistake in the escape characters:

```
FUNCTION getReportData(
    P_DATE_FROM IN DATE,
    P_DATE_TO IN DATE,
    PERIOD_TYPE IN INTEGER)
 
RETURN RPTTCI1328_TABLE PIPELINED IS TYPE cursorOutput IS REF CURSOR;
   
    CUR_ROW RPTTCI1328_ROW;
    cur_getByPeriodFilter cursorOutput;
    c_stmt_str VARCHAR2 (4000);
 
  BEGIN

IF PERIOD_TYPE = 1 THEN
 c_stmt_str :=
' SELECT TO_CHAR(tcis_case.offence_datetime, ''yyyy'') YEAR, tcis_case.status, COUNT(tcis_case.ticket_no) TICKET_NO, ' ||
' SUM(tcis_part_payment.AMT_ORIGINAL) ORIGINAL, ' ||
' SUM(tcis_part_payment.AMT_PAID) PAID, ' ||
' SUM(CASE WHEN tcis_person.reason_code = ''A'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) A, ' ||
' SUM(CASE WHEN tcis_person.reason_code = ''D'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) D, ' ||
' SUM(CASE WHEN tcis_person.reason_code = ''F'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) F, ' ||
' SUM(CASE WHEN tcis_person.reason_code = ''N'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) N, ' ||
' SUM(CASE WHEN tcis_person.reason_code = ''O'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) O, ' ||
' SUM(CASE WHEN tcis_person.reason_code = ''INF'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INF, ' ||
' SUM(CASE WHEN tcis_person.reason_code = ''WFR'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WFR ' ||
' FROM tcis_case ' ||
' join tcis_part_payment on tcis_case.tcis_case_id = tcis_part_payment.tcis_case_id ' ||
' join tcis_person on tcis_case.tcis_case_id = tcis_person.tcis_case_id ' ||
' where tcis_person.person_no = 1 ' ||
' AND tcis_case.unit = ''M'' ' ||
' AND tcis_case.sub_unit = ''P'' ' ||
' AND tcis_case.status IN (''P'', ''C'') ' ||
' AND (''' || P_DATE_FROM ||''' IS NULL OR  tcis_case.offence_datetime >= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(''' || P_DATE_FROM ||''', ''yyyy''),''yyyy'')) ' ||
' AND (''' || P_DATE_TO ||''' IS NULL OR tcis_case.offence_datetime < TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(''' || P_DATE_TO ||''', ''YYYY''),''yyyy'')) ' ||
' GROUP BY to_char(tcis_case.offence_datetime, ''yyyy''), tcis_case.status '; 
END If;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (c_stmt_str); 
      OPEN cur_getByPeriodFilter FOR c_stmt_str;
      LOOP
         FETCH cur_getByPeriodFilter INTO
           CUR_ROW.YEAR,
           CUR_ROW.STATUS,                                           
           CUR_ROW.TICKET_COUNT,                                            
           CUR_ROW.ORIGINAL,                       
           CUR_ROW.PAID, 
           CUR_ROW.A,
           CUR_ROW.D,
           CUR_ROW.F,                                        
           CUR_ROW.N,                       
           CUR_ROW.O,       
           CUR_ROW.INF,
           CUR_ROW.WFR;                                                    
           EXIT WHEN cur_getByPeriodFilter%NOTFOUND;
           PIPE ROW(CUR_ROW);
        END LOOP;
       CLOSE cur_getByPeriodFilter;
     END;
```

The command from sqlplus is:

```
select pkg_name.function('DD-MMM-YY','DD-MMM-YY', 1) from dual;
```

Comment: `AMT_ORIGINAL`and `AMT_PAID` are most probably VARCHAR2, aren't they`? Check your numeric NLS setting then. Also consider using *bind variables* in the cursor definition.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an excerpt of a larger "code" you composed as a **string**. This is usually done when there's something *dynamic* you're working with, such as passing table or column names as procedure's parameters. What is your reason to do that? Maybe I didn't notice it, but - I don't see anything dynamic here.

If that's so, you can skip all those single quotes and write a nice, "normal" `SELECT` statement, without escaping *anything*.

However, if you insist on it (or there's really a reason I didn't see), consider using the q-quoting mechanism. This is what you're doing now (using zillion of single quotes; difficult to read, follow and debug):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(200);
  5    l_res varchar2(1);
  6  begin
  7    l_str := 'select ''A'' first_column from dual';
  8    execute immediate l_str into l_res;
  9    return l_res;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(null) from dual;

F_TEST(NULL)
-------------------------------------------------------------
A

SQL>
```

Or, you can do it this way:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(200);
  5    l_res varchar2(1);
  6  begin
  7    l_str := q'[select 'A' first_column from dual]';        --> this
  8    execute immediate l_str into l_res;
  9    return l_res;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(null) from dual;

F_TEST(NULL)
------------------------------------------------------------
A

SQL>
```

So:

- use the `q` *keyword*,
- open a single quote
- use e.g. square bracket (if you don't use it in your code; if you do, use something else)
- write your query as you usually do
- close the bracket
- close the single quote

As simple as that.

---

Comment you posted says that nothing much happened (except that code is now, probably, somewhat simpler).

I don't have your data so I can't test it myself - you'll have to find the culprit yourself, there's just too much code.

Error you got says (for example) this:

```
SQL> select to_number('A') from dual;
select to_number('A') from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Oracle tells you the position of the error - can you find something out of it?

Comment: This was wonderful and very helpful! I had looked at the q'[]'; solution but still cannot find a way to incorporate the parameters P_DATE_TO and P_DATE_FROM as they are still not recognized.

Comment: Ok, got the q'[]' notation working with parameters and now I am back to the same error of ORA-01722: invalid number. So I am back where I started from.

Comment: I added some more info; have a look.

Answer (score 0):

A *mistake in the escape characters* will lead to a problem with the `OPEN` of the cursor

`ORA-01722: invalid number error` is runtime error where you fail to convert a string to a number in the `FETCH`.

You may try to figure out which column it is by *trial and error* (replace stepwise each numeric column with `null`), but is is most probably `AMT_ORIGINAL`or `AMT_PAID`.

If the column is `VARCHAR2` and you see values such as `100,50` or `100.50` the problem is that yours `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`does not match.

You must explicit convert the string to number with the proper setting. e.g. for `100.50`

```
sum(to_number(AMT_PAID, '9999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'''))
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572074/4808122) answer for more details.

**Additional Comments**

- if you pass in a `DATE` parameter you do not need the double conversion `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(` use simple the parameter
- you do not need a dynamic cursor, if you would use *bind variables* which is recommended. See the simplified implementation below
- You may want to you a dynamic cursor to get efficient execution plan for the search with and without the date range - see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56778621/4808122)

**Simplified Implementation**

```
CREATE or replace  FUNCTION getReportData(
    P_DATE_FROM IN DATE,
    P_DATE_TO IN DATE)
 RETURN RPTTCI1328_TABLE PIPELINED IS 

   CURSOR cur_getByPeriodFilter 
   IS
   SELECT to_char(offence_datetime,'YYYY') year,
   /* process mumeric strings with decimal point e.g. 100.50 */
   sum(to_number(AMT_PAID, '9999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'''))  
   from tab
   where tab.offence_datetime >= P_DATE_FROM and tab.offence_datetime < P_DATE_TO
   group by  to_char(offence_datetime,'YYYY')
   ;   
   CUR_ROW RPTTCI1328_ROW := RPTTCI1328_ROW(null,null);
   
BEGIN
      OPEN cur_getByPeriodFilter;
      LOOP
         FETCH cur_getByPeriodFilter INTO
           CUR_ROW.YEAR,
           CUR_ROW.PAID;
           EXIT WHEN cur_getByPeriodFilter%NOTFOUND;
           PIPE ROW(CUR_ROW);
      END LOOP;        
END;
/
```

Comment: My Understanding is that you need a REF CURSOR to use IF ELSE...