# How to create a dynamic where clause in Oracle (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oci8

I have the below query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM FOO
WHERE LOCATION = :LOCATION
AND MY_DATE >= TIMESTAMP :BEGIN AND MY_DATE <= TIMESTAMP :END -- option 1 if :BEGIN & :END is not NULL
AND MY_DATE >= TIMESTAMP :BEGIN AND MY_DATE <= sysdate        -- option 2 if :BEGIN is not NULL & :END is NULL
AND MY_DATE <= TIMESTAMP :END                                 -- option 3 if :BEGIN is NULL & :END is not NULL
AND MY_DATE <= sysdate                                        -- option 4 if both :BEGIN & :END is NULL
ORDER BY MY_DATE;
```

so here `:LOCATION` is supplied by the user on code level using `OCI8`. For example:

```rb
require 'oci8'
cursor = conn.parse(query)
cursor.bind_param(':LOCATION', 'Chicago', String)
```

I only want one of the options from 1 to 4 to be part of the final query. For example if option 3 is true (`:BEGIN` is `NULL` & `:END` is not `NULL`) then the final query will be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM FOO
WHERE LOCATION = :LOCATION
AND MY_DATE <= TIMESTAMP :END                                 -- option 3 if :BEGIN is not NULL & :END is NULL
ORDER BY MY_DATE;
```

Where user would supply an `:END` date

```rb
require 'oci8'
cursor = conn.parse(query)
cursor.bind_param(':LOCATION', 'Chicago', String)
cursor.bind_param(':START', NULL)
cursor.bind_param(':END', '2001-01-22 12:01:00', String)
```

and would result in:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM FOO
WHERE LOCATION = 'chicago'
AND MY_DATE <= TIMESTAMP '2001-01-22 12:01:00'
ORDER BY MY_DATE;
```

How do I write a query to allow this logic?

Comment: You may use `my_date >= coalesce(:begin, date '0001-01-01') and my_date <= coalesce(:end, date '9999-12-31' + interval '23:59:59' hour to second)`

Comment: Answer for a similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56778621/4808122) showing the *trick* how to generate a dynamic SQL, so that you have the same number of *bind variables* for all options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `CASE` :

```
SELECT *
  FROM FOO
 WHERE LOCATION = :LOCATION
   AND MY_DATE >= CASE WHEN :BEGIN IS NOT NULL THEN :BEGIN
                       ELSE MY_DATE
                  END
   AND MY_DATE <= CASE WHEN :END IS NOT NULL THEN :END
                       ELSE SYSDATE
                  END
 ORDER BY MY_DATE;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the first clause would work if `:BEGIN = NULL` as it would result in `AND MY_DATE >=MY_DATE`. Instead it would be better if we hard-coded it as `AND MY_DATE >= CASE WHEN :BEGIN IS NOT NULL THEN :BEGIN ELSE '1990-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: You got greater or equal, if you compare MY_DATE with MY_DATE it will return true (basically remove the condition), which is what you need. Moreover, putting the hardcoded value limits the use of your query, which is generally bad.

Answer (score 0):

wondering if you exchanged the comments for options 2 and 3? I see you are using :BEGIN and :END when they are NULL

```
AND MY_DATE >= TIMESTAMP :BEGIN AND MY_DATE <= sysdate        -- option 2 if :BEGIN is NULL & :END is not NULL
AND MY_DATE <= TIMESTAMP :END                                 -- option 3 if :BEGIN is not NULL & :END is NULL
```

I think you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM FOO
WHERE LOCATION = :LOCATION
and my_date BETWEEN nvl(:BEGIN,'1900-01-01 00:00:00') and nvl(:END,sysdate)
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I made a correction.

Comment: Does this take into account the change in <= and >=?

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive which means it will work exactly as >= & <=. 
Also notice that on my query I put a default lower bound value of '1900-01-01 00:00:00' if :BEGIN is null, which in most of the cases I think should work.