# How to write this SQL where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simplified a SQL report that was requested. One of the parameters is to allow them to enter how many days they want the data/rows to go back e.g. they enter 10 days but if they enter nothing, currently it fetches everything from the last 90 days.

He's come back asking if there's a way to fetch everything if no value is supplied (currently it fetches only the last 90 days of data)

I have tried nvl only so far -

```sql
Select * 
From timesheets
Where transaction_date between trunc(sysdate-nvl('&Days','90')) and trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL - How to build where clause with optional search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454886/oracle-sql-how-to-build-where-clause-with-optional-search-parameters)

Comment: Also note that `nvl` evaluates to string and there's no subtraction defined for strings. It causes implicit type conversion that is not necessary

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56778621/4808122) answer using a *dynamic SQL* that leads to a different SQL for the case the parameter is set or leaved out. The point is  for a non trivial queries you often need a *different* execution plan for the two cases (e.g. full scan vs. index access) - this is not possible with a single SQL using `or` resp. `nvl`...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select * from timesheets
where transaction_date >= trunc(sysdate) - :par_days
   or :par_days is null;
```

Example (SQL*Plus, using substitution variable):

```
SQL> with timesheets (id, transaction_date) as
  2    (select 1, date '1990-02-18' from dual union all
  3     select 2, date '2022-08-15' from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2023-07-22' from dual union all
  5     select 4, date '2023-09-07' from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from timesheets
  9  where transaction_date >= trunc(sysdate) - '&&par_days'
 10     or '&&par_days' is null;
Enter value for par_days:

        ID TRANSACTIO      --> par_days is NULL - all rows are returned
---------- ----------
         1 18.02.1990
         2 15.08.2022
         3 22.07.2023
         4 07.09.2023

SQL> undefine par_days
SQL> /
Enter value for par_days: 30

        ID TRANSACTIO     --> rows within last 30 days
---------- ----------
         4 07.09.2023

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   timesheets
WHERE  transaction_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    ('&Days' IS NULL OR transaction_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '&&Days' DAY)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   timesheets
WHERE  transaction_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
AND    (:Days IS NULL OR transaction_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - :Days)
```

*Note: If you have the upper-bound as `transaction_date <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)` then you get everything before or equal to midnight today and exclude all the rows from 1 second after midnight today. If you use `transaction_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1` then you get everything before or equal to any time today. If your `DATE` column only contains values with a midnight time component then both will behave equally but if you have non-midnight time components then you need to check which business logic you want to implement (probably anytime today rather than only midnight).*